# MSWord replaces word BUTTON with {HYPERLINK }

Tags: ms-word

I have a word document(say x.doc) that has word `Button` at many many places. All of a sudden, where ever there is `Button`, I see following text

```
{HYPERLINK "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/something.aspx"}
```

I highlight above text, R-click and click `Remove Hyperlink` or `Select Hyperlink`. Then the `{HYPERLINK....}` gets replaced with word Button. This is what I want.

I have spent days working on this document. Now all I see is HYPER Link.

Please tell me how to fix this(I want to see Button, not this hyper link). 
Any idea how could this happened?

I am using 2003 word.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Press **Alt** + **F9**.

Have fun,
Adam

Comment: Thanks for responding. Alt + F9 did not work. But Shift+CTRL +F9 worked. SelectALL followed by Shift+CTRL +F9 removed HYPERLINK. Then I saved the file. I reopened the file and did not see any more HYPERLINK. And that was good